Audible preview about a mother and her daughters who live in a community with shifters
This book came up on preview on Audible and now I can't find it. Only heard the first 4 or so minutes.
A mother and her daughters live in a community with shifters. Oldest daughter comes home and is furious with mother for signing her up for the local mating contest. Once you have been entered there is no going back. Sisters tease mother for her reply saying that mom's comeback response is her tell that she did the deed.

Set in the present day? Ancient Sumeria? THe far-flung future?

Shifters? As in furniture movers? Or shapeshifters?  Would be much clearer if you'd typed out the entire word.  There is no shortage of letters online, you don't have to try to ration them.

@JK. nd hrs me trng t' cnsrv ths fnite rsrce :)

@TARA  I would assume shifters were tools used sort powders by size, small particles passing through the shifters and large particles remaining trapped inside them.
